# Raspberry Pi Signage using omxplayer and LXDE-pi with RTMP, delay for WiFi connectivity

Tags: omxplayer, lxde

I am using several Raspberry Pi 3B+ around this company. I have these Pi’s configured to automatically start playing an RTMP stream using omxplayer.

I did this by adding the following to /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart:

```
@unclutter -idle 0
@omxplayer rtmp://10.70.1.125:1936/live/signage
```

This works pretty well for most Pi’s, but some are in remote area’s with bad WiFi coverage. Due to this, the Pi’s take longer to connect to the network. This causes omxplayer to start playing the RTMP stream when there isn’t a network connection yet, causing it to fail.
I would like to add a delay to the following commands being run, for example:

```
@(Command to delay for 5-10 seconds)
@unclutter -idle 0
@omxplayer rtmp://10.70.1.125:1936/live/signage
```

I have tried the “sleep” command but to no avail.

Is there anything that I am looking over and that any of you guys might know?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Configure the Raspberry Pi (in `raspi-config`) to wait for network on boot.